# how to use bibliographystyle unsrt

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, numbering

I have posted a question regarding this matter in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228034/how-to-change-bibtex-orders-citations-from-alphabetically-to-numerically). Some ppl suggest me to use `unsrt` for numeric case of citations since I'm using `.bib`. This works sometimes and sometimes switches to another mode that I don't want. To illustrate the problem, this is code my code

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

hshshhhs \cite{2}     \cite{1}  \cite{3}  \cite{4}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{references}{}


\end{document}
```

The references.bib is

```
@article{1, 
    author ={H. Durrant-Whyte, T. Bailey},
    title = {Simultaneous localization and mapping: part I},
    publisher = "Robotics Automation Magazine, IEEE",
    year = {2006},
    volume  = "13",
    pages = {99-110}
}

@incollection{2,
year={1996},
isbn={978-1-4471-1257-0},
booktitle={Robotics Research},
editor={Giralt, Georges and Hirzinger, Gerhard},
doi={10.1007/978-1-4471-1021-7_69},
title={Localization of Autonomous Guided Vehicles},
url={http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4471-1021-7_69},
publisher={Springer London},
author={Durrant-Whyte, Hugh and Rye, David and Nebot, Eduardo},
pages={613-625},
language={English}
}

@book{3, 
author = "Mr. X", 
title = {Mr. X Knows BibTeX}, 
publisher = "AWOL", 
YEAR = 2005, 
}

@misc{ 4,
       author = "Nobody Jr",
       title = "My Article",
       year = "2006" }
```

The output is

[image]

Since I'm using `\cite{2}`, I'm expecting the output to be `[2]` but for somehow latex rearranges the references list to something I don't want. It is so confusing now. Any suggestions why this occurs.

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228034/how-to-change-bibtex-orders-citations-from-alphabetically-to-numerically

Comment: `unsrt` numbers citations in the order they appear in the document. The `2` in the `\cite{}` command and in the `.bib` file is just the "key" that's used to refer to the entry; it has nothing to do with the numbering of the citations.

Comment: @PaulGessler, how can I get the output that I'm looking for. This will simplify my citations.

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you could explain the basis of the order you are trying to achieve. Since the reader won't have access to the `.bib` file, I'm assuming you are trying to impose an order on the sort by arranging entries in a particular way in that file. But that is not how it works. So can you tell us what that order is?

Comment: Using numeric keys in a bibtex file is not actually a syntax error but is extremely weird and will be very confusing. The bibtex keys are like `\label` keys they are just internal identifiers.

Comment: I suppose you could use `\nocite` to force the order, but why? I don't see how it could simplify the citations: the whole point of BibTeX is to make it so you don't have to worry about any of this stuff.

Comment: I was hoping to use numbers in `\cite{}` that matches my references list so that I don't have to label the references by names. This helps me not the reader while I'm writing my paper. But it doesn't seem it is gonna work that way. I will go back and label them by names.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, this is true. This is why I'm asking however IEEE uses numbers for labeling the papers.

Comment: The print form is unrelated to the key used in the bib file, that is just for cross referencing with `\cite`.

Comment: The two normal orders that bibtex styles use are alphabetic order of authors, or order of first use with \cite. You appear to want to force a different arbitrary order, which you can do with `\nocite` but it seems very unusual, why do you need that number order?

Comment: @CroCo as with `\label` using "the same numbers" is ultimately confusing as the whole point of these kind of systems is that you can make an edit (say adding a new reference) and everything re-numbers automatically, but then you are left with `\cite{3}` producing `[4]` which doesn't confuse latex but is likely to confuse you:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, `nocite` did the trick. Having said that, I will certainly reconsider using names instead of numbers even though numbers to me much clearly than names especially if I have multiple papers for the same author.

Comment: @CroCo in 25 years that's the first bibtex file I've seen with numeric keys, but there is a first time for everything:-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`unsrt` numbers citations in the order they appear in the document. The `2` in the `\cite{}` command and in the `.bib` file is just the "key" that's used to refer to the entry; it has nothing to do with the numbering of the citations.

I don't see how it could simplify the citations: the whole point of BibTeX is to make it so you don't have to worry about any of this stuff (see my notes below).

You can use `\nocite{<keys>}` to force the order.

But first, in general, numerical keys are very confusing:

- Say you add a citation to the beginning of the document. Will you then go back through and re-name every single key and reference to it?
- When writing the document, most people say,

  > Oh, here I need to cite Duckington's first paper from 1998!

  and write `\cite{duckington98a}` or whatever pattern they've chosen, *not*

  > Oh, now I'm on citation *n*, let me type `\cite{n}` and then go add an entry to my `.bib` file with exactly that number.
- Multiple cites: you'll have to constantly go back and remember what number belongs with what reference. If you use author names this is much easier to commit to memory.

Here's how you could do it if you really wanted to:

```
\begin{filecontents}{myrefs.bib}
@article{1, 
    author ={H. Durrant-Whyte, T. Bailey},
    title = {Simultaneous localization and mapping: part I},
    publisher = "Robotics Automation Magazine, IEEE",
    year = {2006},
    volume  = "13",
    pages = {99-110}
}

@incollection{2,
year={1996},
isbn={978-1-4471-1257-0},
booktitle={Robotics Research},
editor={Giralt, Georges and Hirzinger, Gerhard},
doi={10.1007/978-1-4471-1021-7_69},
title={Localization of Autonomous Guided Vehicles},
url={http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4471-1021-7_69},
publisher={Springer London},
author={Durrant-Whyte, Hugh and Rye, David and Nebot, Eduardo},
pages={613-625},
language={English}
}

@book{3, 
author = "Mr. X", 
title = {Mr. X Knows BibTeX}, 
publisher = "AWOL", 
YEAR = 2005, 
}

@misc{ 4,
       author = "Nobody Jr",
       title = "My Article",
       year = "2006" }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\nocite{1,2,3,4} % force the order here
hshshhhs \cite{2}     \cite{1}  \cite{3}  \cite{4}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{myrefs}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\nocite` is what I'm looking for but I will definitely reconsider using names instead of numbers.